# JPA - calculated column as entity class property?

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Relatively new to JPA, so I have one kind of architectural question.
Let's say I have tables EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT with many to one relationship (i.e. many employees work for one department):

```
EMPLOYEE
  EMPLOYEE_ID
  EMPLOYEE_NAME
  DEPARTMENT_ID 

DEPARTMENT
  DEPARTMENT_ID
  DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

So I can define proper entities for Employee and Department, there's no problem. However, in one view I would like to display list of departments with number of employees working for that department, something like this:

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES
FROM DEPARTMENT D
```

I'm just not sure what is the right strategy to accomplish this using JPA...
I don't want to always fetch number of employees for Department entity, as there is only one view when it is needed.

It looks like Hibernate's @Formula would be one possible approach, but afaik it does not conform with JPA standard.

Answer (score 4):

You can create any object in your QL using the "new" syntax - your class just needs a constructor that takes the values returned by your query.

For example, with a class like DepartmentEmployeeCount, with a constructor:

```
public DepartmentEmployeeCount(String departmentName, Integer employeeCount)
```

you could use QL something like:

```
SELECT NEW DepartmentEmployeeCount(D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(E.id)) from Department D left join D.employees E GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

Or if you were just selecting the count(*) you could simply cast the query result to a Number.

Alternatively, to do the same without the DepartmentEmployeeCount class, you could leave out the NEW, so:

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(E.id)
```

This would return a `List<Object[]>` where each list item was an array of 2 elements, departmentName and count.

To answer your later question in the comments, to populate all fields of a Department plus a transient employeeCount field, one suggestion would be to do 2 queries. This would still be more efficient than your original query (a subselect for each employee count).

So one query to read the departments

```
SELECT D from Department D
```

giving you a `List<Department>`

Then a 2nd query returning a temporary array:

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_ID, count(E.id) from Department D left join D.employees E GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

giving you a `List<Object[]>` with DEPARTMENT_ID and count in it.

Then you use the 2nd list to update the transient count property on your first list.
(You could try selecting into a Map to make this lookup easier, but I think that's a Hibernate feature).

Comment: Thank you @MattR for your answer. This solution might work for this simple example. But what if (a) DEPARTMENT table has many other columns in addition to NAME and I obviously don't want to list all of them in the constructor and (b) I still want to have it as property of Department entity (with LAZY fetch type) to be accessible somewhere else just in case.

Comment: Good question, I haven't tried it but I *think* you can use entity classes in the constructor (so you wouldn't need to select all the entity properties). If I get a chance to try it I'll update my answer... ie you could have a DepartmentEmployees class (say) that had a constructor DepartmentEmployees(Department, Integer) and use SELECT new DepartmentEmployees(D, count(E.id))  - not quite what you're asking for but closer...

Comment: OK I was thinking about this one over lunch, so updated some extra info. If you try any of the suggestions or find a better solution, please report back

Comment: Yes, two queries is what originally came to my mind. I was hoping there's something more elegant, either one query to load everything, or lazy-fetching property (one could use either approach, depending on specifics of real-life scenario).

Comment: You can use one query if you use a constructor, you probably wouldn't want lazy fetching unless you want to leave transactions/sessions open all the way to the view... And 2 queries is better than (1 + #employees) queries :-)

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: I suggested this since you didn't like the constructor route MattR was suggesting.  You mentioned the word "view" several times, and I know you were talking about the view to the user, but why not setup a view in your database that includes the computed columns and then create a read-only entity that maps to the computed columns?

Option 2: In response to your comment about not wanting to create a view. You could create a container object that holds the entity and the calculated column, then much like MattR suggests, you use a new in your select.  Something like:

```
public class DepartmentInfo {
    private Department department;

    // this might have to be long or something
    // just see what construct JPA tries to call
    private int employeeCount;

    public DepartmentInfo( Department d, int count ) { 
        department = d;
        employeeCount = count;
    }
    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then your select becomes

```
SELECT new my.package.DepartmentInfo( D, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID))
FROM DEPARTMENT D
```

With that you can use the DepartmentInfo to get the properties you are interested in.

Comment: That's possible, indeed. But what I want is just an extra property for my existing entity, that I can use on one page (and, possibly, somewhere else). Is it really worth creating another view and another entity for that?

Comment: What you want _right now_ is just an extra property for your existing entity to use on one page, and possibly another.  And in the future possibly 3 more with possibly 4 more extra properties and so on and so on.  In any case, I've added option 2 to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @digitaljoel, so far that looks like the most optimal approach in this scenario.

Comment: One last thought, if you have an association from Department to Employee (which it looks like you easily could given your mapping) then I believe you could change the query to something much smaller `SELECT new my.package.DepartmentInfo( D, SIZE(D.Employees)) from DEPARTMENT D`

Comment: @digitaljoel I haven't tried the SIZE() function, that would be a good solution. You'd probably need to specify the join "from DEPARTMENT D join D.EMPLOYEES" to avoid multiple queries. For the same reason, I'd avoid the Select (D, COUNT(*)) approach...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a member in your entity as an additional column, and then reference it with an alias in your query. The column name in the `@Column` annotation must match the alias.

Say, for your original query, you can add a `countEmployees` member as following. Also add `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` so the entity manager wont try to include it in insert or update statements:

```
public class Department {

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    Long departmentId;

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    String departmentName;

    @Column(name="countEmployees", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    Long countEmployees;

    //accessors omitted

}
```

And your query:

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS countEmployees
FROM DEPARTMENT D
```

This also applies when working with Spring Data Jpa Repositories.

Comment: Can you do the same using a JPA query, not a native one?