# Native SQL query with table join doesn't work with Spring's JpaRepository

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have this Dao class with native SQL query that joins results from 2 tables:

```
public interface NotificationDao extends JpaRepository<Notification, Long> {

    String query = """
        SELECT n.*, CASE WHEN rn.notification_id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END as read 
        FROM notification n
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT notification_id, user_id
            FROM read_notification
            WHERE user_id = ?1 OR user_id IS NULL
        ) rn
        ON n.id = rn.notification_id
        WHERE n.deleted IS FALSE
        AND (n.user_id IS NULL OR n.user_id = ?1) 
        OFFSET (?2*?3) ROWS FETCH NEXT ?2 ROWS ONLY 
        """;
    
    @Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Notification> findAllNotifications(String userId, Integer size, Integer page);
}
```

And this entity class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "notification_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "notification_gen", sequenceName = "notification_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NotificationType type;

    private String text;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Transient
    private boolean read;
}
```

Result of calling `findAllNotifications` doesn't have values for field `read` (read = null).
I tried SQL statement in console and it works fine; I get table with `read` column populated as expected. What do I need to do to make it work.

Also, I have made it work by returning `List<Object[]>` from `NotificationDao` class and mapping results by hand to `List<Notification`:

```
private List<Notification> mapQueryResultsToNotifications(List<Object[]> results) {
        return results.stream()
                .map(result -> {
                    Notification notification = new Notification();
                    notification.setId((Long) result[0]);
                    String notificationType = result[2] != null ? (String) result[7] : NotificationType.GENERAL.toString();
                    notification.setType(NotificationType.valueOf(notificationType));
                    notification.setText((String) result[1]);
                    notification.setUserId((String) result[3]);
                    notification.setRead((Boolean) result[4]);
                    return notification;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

List<Notification> notifications = mapQueryResultsToNotifications(notificationDao.findUnreadNotifications(userId, size, page));

@Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> findAllNotifications(String userId, Integer size, Integer page);
```

But it makes sense to me it could be done cleaner. This way every time I make a change to query I need to change mapping in `mapQueryResultsToNotifications`

Comment: Just remove `@Transient`.

Comment: The second issue, which should probably be a separate question, is not clear why manual mapping would be needed.  Please clarify (in a new question).

Comment: @Pino Removing `@Transient` is not possible because notification table doesn't have column 'read'; spring is throwing exception

Comment: @AndrewS Manual mapping is needed because otherwise field 'read' is not populated (read=null)

Comment: OK, now I see that your native query contains a calculated column named `read`.  In this case the correct question describing your problem is "How can I populate a calculated column with a native query in JPA?" and it has already been asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA - calculated column as entity class property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403924/jpa-calculated-column-as-entity-class-property)